# Formatting of dataframe index and columns using styler

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, pandas-styles

I am quite new with `html` and the `pandas dataframe styler`, but here is my problem:

I wrote the following code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1000000.0, 1000000.0], index=pd.bdate_range('2017-08-01', '2017-08-02'))

styler = df.style
styler = styler.format("{:,.0f}")
styler = styler.set_properties(**{'width': '100px', 'text-align': 'right'})
```

Which yield the following

[image]

I understand how to format the various elements of the `dataframe` I am working with. However, I would like to format my `index` and `column` title. In particular, i would like to format my `index` as a date without the time, and I would like to align my `column` name to the right, like I did with my values. More specifically, is there an efficient to access the `index` and `columns` in the `pandas styler`.

Comment: One of the limitations of the styler: "You can only style the values, not the index or columns". https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Limitations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this, see [table styles](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Table-Styles):

```
import pandas as pd
​
df = pd.DataFrame([1000000.0, 1000000.0], index=pd.bdate_range('2017-08-01', '2017-08-02'))
​
df.index = df.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
styler = df.style
styler = styler.format("{:,.0f}")
styler = styler.set_properties(**{'width': '100px', 'text-align': 'right'})

styler.set_table_styles(
# select the table header with th and set it right align
    [dict(selector="th", props=[("text-align", "right")])]   
)
```

[image]

Comment: You might even put a firstchild pseudo selector on a tr to nail down only the first th... If that'd ever be a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped!